# SupportMapFragment make app crashed after getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

i have a problem to access SupportMapFragment, 
in this part of my code, its always returning NPE,

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Here is my fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my MainActivity.java

```
//...
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        } else { 
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();        

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));       
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            // Part of my code that i get NPE
            // my code running well if i commenting this section
            //googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();               
            if (googleMap != null) {

            }
        }
    }
//...
```

and here my PlaceholderFragment

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);                     

            return rootView;
        }
```

i think my manifest works fine, because everything is fine before i used 
`googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)`
but, for clearing my question, here my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- Not Required in Map API v2 but highly recomended -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" 
            android:required="true"
            />

        <!-- Initiating Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.InitiatingActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Welcome Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Login Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXX" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and here my log cat that explain to me NPE problem :

```
06-02 18:32:04.292: W/dalvikvm(32016): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d0b2a0)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh/yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MainActivity.java:84)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at yai.properti.tujuh.tujuh.tujuh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
06-02 18:32:04.297: E/AndroidRuntime(32016):    ... 11 more
```

I have tried to find solution in SO, but no one can solve my problem,
i have tried to :

1. Used MapFragment by following this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) but not solved my question.
2. Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17469939) and still give me some error.
3. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489022) not helped too.
4. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029015/app-crash-when-trying-to-access-mapfragment) question and not fixing my problem, so i make a new question here in SO.
5. Following this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/), [link](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-mapfragment-example/), and another [link](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-maps-android-api-v2-mapfragment.html) but no one can solve my problem.
6. My Google play services work properly, so its not from Google Play Services.

Any advice? what's solution? many thanks, i really need this for my collage final project, any help would be appreciated it.

**UPDATE**

line 84 on Log Cat is :

`googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: once debug and check at line number 84 there some thing went null..

Comment: @shylendra thanks for your reply, thats my `googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: instead of `ActionBarActivity` u can use `FragmentActivity` and give it a try

Comment: @john : where you have wrote that line in your code??

Comment: yes, what kaushik said is right you need to extend FragmentActivity

Comment: @kaushik thanks for your reply, I need ActionBarActivity to show action bar in my app, so can we extends ActionBarActivity and use SupportMapFragment to show map rather than using Extends FragmentActivity? Or maybe Google map v2 is always extend by Fragment activity? I have tried all solution that given from this SO and still NPE, any ideas?

Comment: @kaushik i want make app like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ziprealty.mobile.android (on second picture) can it be made using FragmentActivity?

Comment: @John : actually I never try that sorry

Comment: @John : check my answer I think that will solve ur problem better option is try to use `MapView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your requirement you can see this link for `GoogleMap v2` with `ActionBar`
**[Git hub link](https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock)**

https://github.com/ddewaele/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock

or u can use **[MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview)** in your activity

- [How to use MapView for GoogleMap v2](https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if (googleMap == null) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            Log.i("Google map", "Successfully Googlemap is opened");
}
```

**Note:** You need to extend FragmentActivity instead of ActionBarActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to do like following :

**XML :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Your MainActivity :**

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_post);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.map);

        initilizeMap(); 
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
```

You override onResume Method and you initilize the Map. This should work ;)

Comment: Is there a reason you call the method initializeMap twice?

Answer (score 0):

```
private GoogleMap map;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

// in onCreate() or in onStart() do some thing like this

fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.maps_parks);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

In xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity:-

```
    public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
        // Google Map
        public GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            Log.e("loading map. . . .", "loading map. . . ");
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("catch. . .", "catch. . .");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         * MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality(); mf.currentLoc();
         * mf.addMarker();
         */
    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        // MapFunctionality mf = new MapFunctionality();
        Log.e("initializing map. . . ", "initializing map. . ");
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            // mf.currentLoc();
            // mf.addMarker();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }
}
```

Follow these [Link 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) and [Link 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)
Hope it will help you to sort out with your problem 
Good Luck