# Android InflateException for MapView from XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been using GoogleMaps in Android for quite a while without any problems but now suddenly without making any changes I'm getting an InflateException when trying to inflate a MapView from XML. I've searched for a solution and all I've found is to add the library correctly which I know I've already done since it worked before. This is my code:

XML file with MapView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
/>
```

OnCreateView() method where I inflate the MapView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

            mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            map = mapView.getMap();
}
```

Error Log:

```
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at net.multieducator.telaviv.MainActivity$Map.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:948)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:850)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2213)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5431)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    ... 46 more
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
08-23 09:42:14.340: E/AndroidRuntime(30030):    ... 49 more
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: @Haresh, I've already done that multiple times and I used it for it to work many times before

Comment: @Axarydax yes, multiple times

Comment: Did u import Google Play Services Library in your Project ?

Comment: in the bottom of the log it says `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` - I think it's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372391/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-rstyleable (see the first answer about adding Google Play Services into your project)

Comment: @rahul kapoor yes, I followed Google's guide to the letter, would it help for an answer if I posted my manifest?

Comment: @Axarydax, I've already looked at that post and I tried adding the library again that way but there was no change

Comment: That's strange, are you sure you have the whole library as sources in your workspace (if using eclipse) and then referencing it from your project (instead of having just a `.jar`?

Comment: I added the whole library and in code it finds the classes perfectly

Comment: you can try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23993598/supportmapfragment-make-app-crashed-after-getsupportfragmentmanager/24010570#24010570)

Comment: @Evan check this map inside of fragment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919048/android-android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-8-error-inflatin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 21.3235752;
            double longitude =74.1881265;

            // lets place some 10 random markers

                // random latitude and logitude
                double[] randomLocation = createRandLocation(latitude,
                        longitude);

                // Adding a marker
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1]))
                        .title(" Mapview Test ");



                    //marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);

                // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                    randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * creating random postion around a location for testing purpose only
     */
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions and API**

```
<permission
        android:name="com.example.mapexdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- meta-data before </application> tag -->
       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDxEkfvGvKy.........your api key" />

         <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this may help you

Comment: I'm using a ViewPager, but I'll try

Comment: Its ok.so for that check the permissions you have given in manifest file

Comment: @KrupaPatel why will this help op? `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable` indicates that google play services is not properly referenced

Comment: @Evan you need to reference google play services properly in your android project

Comment: then you just need to remove the reference and give reference it again.

Comment: @Raghunaandan it actually worked!!! I think there was something wrong with the way I was inflating the MapView, very weird

Comment: @Evan no it is because you haven't reference the library project properly. Read the stacktrace with the caused by part.

Comment: @Evan how come you accepted this answer. This has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: @Raghunandan I have referenced it properly and this worked, I have no idea why...

Comment: Why look at stacktrace secondly. This posted code maywork butit is not related to your problem.