# Google Map api v2 application stop working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to run Google maps API v2 on emulator. It says "unfortunately app has stoped" Here is my manifest.xml code. There is a huge number of errors. In the first line it gives error to define android.allowBackup which I have done on application tag.Please help me solve them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permissionandroid:name="com.myapp.providers.gsf.permission.
READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


 <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" /> 
 <!--     <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  -->

<activity
android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="My key"/>
</application>

</manifest>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 MainActivity.java



package myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map = mapFrag.getMap();

   map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);    
}
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

activity_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>



 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Logcat

```
E/Trace(690): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
E/AndroidRuntime(690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(690): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity        

ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:  

Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 15:06:56.709: E/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML         

file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)

android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.
java:110)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
AndroidRuntime(690):    ... 11 more
AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's        

AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0. 
You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:    
<meta-data    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     

android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-01 15:06:56.709: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  ... 23 more
09-01 15:07:53.868: E/Trace(734): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-01 15:07:54.479: E/AndroidRuntime(734): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 15:07:54.479: E/AndroidRuntime(734): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity       ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 15:07:54.479: E/AndroidRuntime(734): Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML         file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.
setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime(734):  ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(734): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your
app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0. 
You must    have the following declaration within the <application> element:   

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"   

android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
(Unknown   Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-01 15:07:54.479: E/AndroidRuntime(734):  ... 23 more
error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}:  
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-01 15:12:22.938: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML 
file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView
(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-01 15:12:22.938: E/AndroidRuntime(811):  ... 11 more
09-01 15:12:22.938: E/AndroidRuntime(811): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-
data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000
but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:  
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-01 15:19:34.508: E/Trace(826): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-01 15:19:35.118: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 15:19:35.118: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException:
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 15:19:35.118: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML
file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView
(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-01 15:19:35.118: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 11 more
09-01 15:19:35.118: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
The meta-               data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not 
have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration
within the <application> element:     
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailabl
(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)

09-01 15:27:57.068: E/Trace(865): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{myapp/myapp.MainActivity}:  
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML 

file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView
(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 11 more
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
The meta-    data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.
Expected        5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the 
<application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable
(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-01 15:27:57.748: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 23 more
```

Comment: you have to post the Logcat

Comment: It is too much that's why I did not post. here it is..

Comment: Instead of run Google map on emulator run on real device

Comment: On a device it still gives the same error :(

Comment: post `layout` and the code where u initialize `google map`

Comment: Kaushik I have edited with full code

Comment: <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1):

mmmh... Change

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="4030500" />
```

to

```
<meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="5089000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp."Your activity name""
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Your map key" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Did the changes but stilling not working. I have edited with full code kindly review them.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below permission to your Manifest.xml

```
<permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

and replaca the below line:

```
<uses-permissionandroid:name="com.myapp.providers.gsf.permission.
READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

via

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.providers.gsf.permission.
READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Comment: Refere tjis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459448/android-inflateexception-for-mapview-from-xml/25459508#25459508. hope this may help you!