# Android Studio : Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, fragment, mapfragment

I'm writing an android app that includes a google map fragment.  When I exclude the map fragment from the activity it's contained in, the app runs fine.  When I include the map fragment, I get the exception quoted in the blockquote below.  The most annoying part about this is that just a few weeks ago this did not happen.  This activity ran perfectly fine for weeks and then I updated android studio and now I'm getting this exception.  I've searched google and several threads on stackoverflow for solutions, nothing works.  I even tried outright copy and pasting the google android demo for a map activity, and I get the same exception.  PLEASE HELP.

The exception raised (copied from android monitor):

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: com.androidapps.seanmcalinden.firstandroidapp, PID: 23089
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidapps.seanmcalinden.firstandroidapp/com.androidapps.seanmcalinden.firstandroidapp.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
>                                                                                                      at com.androidapps.seanmcalinden.firstandroidapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:67)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
>                                                                                                      at com.androidapps.seanmcalinden.firstandroidapp.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:67) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.io.File.mkdir()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.m.ad.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.y.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.bd.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.ev.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.z.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.e.y.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$zza$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$4.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2201)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
>                                                                                                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreat

The OnCreate method:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e("success", "entered onCreate in MapsActivity");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    MapFragment mapFragment =
            (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (locationGAC == null) {
        // ATTENTION: This "addApi(AppIndex.API)"was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        locationGAC = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        Log.e("success", "created locationGAC");
    }

    Log.d("myTag", "test output 1");

    createFriendList();

}
```

The layout file for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:weightSum="1" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Back"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SearchBar1"
        android:onClick="backToLogin"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/SearchBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/SearchButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:onClick="onSearch"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Retrieve"
        android:id="@+id/serverRetrieveButton"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="getLocationFromDexelus"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/serverSendButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="sendLocationToDexelus"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As said above, I've tried many solutions found here on Stackoverflow.  Not to say that you shouldn't post those again, but rather that I think my issue may be more complex or specific than those because none of the given solutions worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide the posts that you already checked so that others would not attempt to duplicate it. You mentioned that this occurred after updating AS, what is the current version of your google-play-services? Will it be possible to post your gradle?

Comment: Check the code in this SO question [17469661](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469661/google-mapfragment-not-working-in-android) and [15703245](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703245/google-maps-fragment-doesnt-load) if it can help you.
Try to use SupportMapFragment instead of just MapFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason when I updated my sdk to the version released on Wednesday, my issues disappeared. I guess this is appropriate since the issues first appeared after an android studio update. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from the line `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`
Maybe the path is not correct.